# Animating the appearance of svg image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, anime.js

Im very new to the animation field so I want to know how can I appear the the UFC fighters in this link I shared? Plus not sure how can I appear the UFC text in the background?
https://watch.screencastify.com/v/0nFPnGwowYSQT86yom7K

Comment: I'm guessing you're wanting to animate the fighters in with the same pixelated effect as that video? You won't be able to do this with GSAP alone. You'll want to look into [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) or [HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) so you can manipulate the graphics. Maybe look into a library like [PixiJS](https://pixijs.com).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help. I will check them out.